# Settings not saved after closing and reopening Firefox on Ubuntu 23.10

Tags: firefox, 23.10

I am using Ubuntu 23.10 and I am writing to report an important problem I noticed in the Firefox browser. I change the settings of my Firefox browser, log into my account and sync my data, but when I close and open the browser, everything is gone and the browser returns to its first use state.

I have tried all browsers and the problem only occurs in Firefox.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Might be a firefox snap issue. Use the APT firefox version, it should work https://askubuntu.com/questions/1399383/how-to-install-firefox-as-a-traditional-deb-package-without-snap-in-ubuntu-22